# FileUpload failure in Ajax UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, file-upload

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [File Upload Control is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482644/file-upload-control-is-not-working)

I have a web page with `FileUpload` control, `Image` control to display uploaded file, `DataList` control to display results of the query. There is a single button to trigger processing: saving image from upload control and passing it for processing to find image matches and displaying them in a grid view control.

I wanted to perform the whole operation flicker free and put all controls into

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID=”UpdatePanel1” runat=”server”>
    <ContentTemplate>
    ...
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

However upon the button click file upload control does not have file. Do I need to separate file upload and image processing logic into 2 buttons from which file upload can not be performed without full page postback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AjaxFileUpload from AJAX control toolkit. You can find the documentation here: http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AjaxFileUpload/AjaxFileUpload.aspx

Comment: have to master it soon, thanks